# Reflection on glass, angle of incidence and ghost image

Tags: reflection, glass

I am using a very thin piece of glass, 0.2mm in thickness (screen protector), located in front of my eye to reflect an image at about 45degrees. The image is located about 1m below the glass. The reflection appears to be crisp and clear. As I rotate the glass and increase the angle of incidence there appears to be a very narrow range, around 50-55degrees, where a secondary ghost image appears, that is a primary reflection and a secondary weaker reflection offset by a small distance. As I continue to increase the angle of incidence the ghost image disappears. If the glass were very thick (more than 3mm) I understand I would see a ghost image in pretty much every angle and the offset of the secondary reflection would depend about the angle of incidence. However since the glass is only 0.2mm thick why does a ghost image form at a very narrow angle of incidence around 50 degrees? Is this a property of physics?

Comment: What happens as the angle increases and the ghost image forms? Is it possible that it is just too difficult to separate visually from the main image for smaller angles?

Comment: Following up on @Peter's comment, maybe as you continue to rotate the glass beyond 55 degrees the separation of primary and ghost images increases to the point where they both don't enter your eye at the same time.

Comment: When I looked for a similar phenomenon on my old mobile phone I found the position of the ghost depended more on its position on the screen than the angle, and the separation of the ghost was affected by pressing the screen?